# Monotonicity of the expectation of random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, monotone-functions

- Define  $r(t)=\frac{1+X_1+...+X_t}{1+Y_1+...+Y_t}$
- $X_t\sim Binomial(Y_t,\alpha)$
- $Y_t \sim Binomial(\lfloor 1+r(t-1)\rfloor,\delta)$

I would like to show that $E[r(t)]$ is a monotonic function of $t$.

Intuitively $E[r(t)]$ should converge to $\alpha$ and therefore $E[r(t)]$ should be a monotonic function.

Any comments or inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: You can just compute $E[r(t)]$, right? Using the linearity property of expectations.

Comment: What are the $Y_i$ here?

Comment: @StanTendijck Admittedly, I can't compute the expectation. (Y1,X1) are not necessarily independent to Y2.

Comment: @Math1000 $Y_i$ are positive integers which are positivley influenced by sum of realized $X_i$.

Comment: @user3509199.  So the $\ Y_i\ $ are *random*, not *fixed*, positive integers? If so, what do know about their distribution?

Comment: Your definition of $X_i$ sort of implies independence between the next values. Otherwise, do you know what kind of dependence structure there lies on the random variables?

Comment: I edited the question for the clarification. Please let me know if there's any confusions..